# Move a UILabel when changing to landscape

Tags: ios, constraints

I have a very simple iOS App (Xcode 8, SWIFT 3), containing a UILabel. It appears some way down the screen when in portrait orientation (Regular, Compact) when using Interface Builder for iPhone 6s. When I rotate to Landscape (Compact, Compact), I cannot get any combination of layouts to move this control to the right-hand half of the landscape view. There is plenty of room for it, but I just cannot work out how to achieve it. I just want it (and a few other controls) to appear in a different place when in Landscape view.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Read [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)